# Dockerized Postgresql : Delete PGDATA content

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to configure replication between two Postgresql docker containers. All tutorials out there - which are based on regular VM, not containers - states that a backup from the Master has to be done in the Replica / StandBy, through a command like this:

```
pg_basebackup -h 192.168.0.108 -U replicator -p 5432 -D $PGDATA -Fp -Xs -P -R
```

Unfortunately, this throws an error:

```
pg_basebackup: error: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
```

I cannot delete the content of this folder because the Postgresql service will crash and I will be kicked out of the container.

So, how can I do this given that I cannot stop the Postgresql service because of the containerized application?

Comment: You would probably have to start a container that is *not* running postgresql by default.  The model would be something like (a) start primary (b) start container for pg_basebackup that populates the postgres data volume then finally (c) start the replica postgres container.

Comment: Thanks for the idea :). Please add a response so I can upvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These instructions following the [percona docs for configuration
postgres replication](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/10/11/how-to-set-up-streaming-replication-in-postgresql-12/).

Create a network for the postgres servers:

```
docker network create pgnet
```

Start the primary database server:

```
docker run -d \
  --network pgnet \
  -v primary_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  --name pg_primary \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret \
  -e POSTGRES_DB=exampledb \
  docker.io/postgres:14
```

Create a replication user and configure `pg_hba.conf` to allow
replication access:

```
docker exec pg_primary \
  psql -U postgres -c \
  "CREATE USER replicator WITH REPLICATION ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'secret'"

docker exec pg_primary \
  sh -c 'echo host replication replicator 0.0.0.0/0 md5 >> $PGDATA/pg_hba.conf'

docker exec pg_primary \
  psql -U postgres -c 'select pg_reload_conf()'
```

Prepare the pgdata directory for the replica server. We do this by running the `pg_basebackup` command in an ephemeral container:

```
docker run -it --rm \
  --network pgnet \
  -v replica_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  --name pg_replica_init \
  docker.io/postgres:14 \
  sh -c 'pg_basebackup -h pg_primary -U replicator -p 5432 -D $PGDATA -Fp -Xs -P -R -W'
```

(The `-W` in the above command forces `pg_basebackup` to prompt for a
password. There are other ways you could provide the password; the
postgres docs have details.)

Start the replica:

```
docker run -d \
  --network pgnet \
  -v replica_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  --name pg_replica \
  docker.io/postgres:14
```

Verify that replication is working.  Create a table in the primary:

```
docker exec pg_primary \
  psql -U postgres exampledb -c 'create table example_table (id int, name text)'
```

See that it shows up in the replica:

```
docker exec pg_replica \
  psql -U postgres exampledb -c '\d'
```

You should see as output:

```
             List of relations
 Schema |     Name      | Type  |  Owner
--------+---------------+-------+----------
 public | example_table | table | postgres
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. There's a tiny problem though with the "exampledb" which is not created at all.

Comment: That's my bad; I dropped an environment variable from the invocation of the primary. I've fixed that in the answer.